Gmail API notifications to PubSub
I am working on some email automation that requires using the GMail API and PubSub as described in the Google document here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push.
This setup requires setting up an OAuth Consent Screen through though which the user can allow using its credentials. This works perfectly on my local laptop that has a openable browser. However, as mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#renewing_mailbox_watch, the watch method has to be called at least every 7 days to keep the watcher active. I need to automate the watcher script by deploying it as a GCP cloud run job. This runtime does not have access to a browser.
I am using the following snipper to trigger the consent screen.
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("client.json", SCOPES, redirect_uri="http://localhost")
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

How can this be achieved through a micro service with no browser access? Please help!
I created a script that calls the watch method of the GMail API, this opens up the local browser and takes the user consent for OAuth credentials usage. I am trying to achieve this through a cloud run job that doesn't have a browser, so that this process can be automated to call the watch API once every 7 days.

You need to create a service account set up with Domain-wide Delegation to allow it to call the watch method as a given user

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
